# Formula Field to Count Records in Lookup Relationshp

Tags: formula, relationships

I want to count the number of child objects in a lookup (not master-detail) relationship. Since no rollup-summary (COUNT) fields are supported I thought I would do this:

```
LEN(GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.MyObj__c))/15
```

Which fails with `Error: Field $ObjectType.MyObj__c does not exist. Check spelling.`

I'm guessing the *real* problem is that SF doesn't support `GETRECORDIDS` in formula fields but I would like to be wrong about this.

Any better ideas aside from triggers?

Comment: Looks like GETRECORDIDS is [documented](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&language=en_US#GETRECORDIDS) as being available only in custom buttons, links and scontrols.

Comment: You are correct, it's weird how they don't have a page which shows you which functions are available in formula fields.

Answer (score 4):

Well `GETRECORDIDS` are probably used in related list to get the ids of the selected records.

You can do the following:

1. **Trigger** (that you don't want)
2. **Inline Visualforce page** : If you just want to display the number of records to the user

Comment: +1. Do not be tempted into making workflow that would add +1 to counter on parent on child insert (or change +1/-1 when child gets reparented) because it won't fire on delete. There's also a nightly batch job route if it doesn't have to be real time...