# A summary formula field in report used to count sum of related lookup records is displaying incorrect value

Tags: formula, data, custom-reports, summary

I believe this question is somewhat related to [Formula Field to Count Records in Lookup Relationshp](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9216/formula-field-to-count-records-in-lookup-relationshp).

I have a 'primary' object called 'Tennis Player' and a 'secondary' object called 'Tennis Reports'.  I have 2 'Tennis Player' records: Andre Agassi and Pete Sampras and 2 'Tennis Reports' records which are both linked to Andre Agassi only:

[image: query editor result]

I have created a custom Report Type of 'Tennis Players with or without Tennis Reports' and have used this report type to create a summary report of tennis players and the count of their respective tennis reports.

I have created a summary formula field in the report to count the unique sum of Tennis Reports:

[image: screenshot of summary formula field]

and I have added this as column in the report. However, this formula is displaying '1' for Pete Sampras but it should return '0' because there are no tennis reports linked to Pete Sampras.

[image]

My understanding is that this is actually standard Salesforce behaviour because there is a 'count' for every summary level. By virtue of 'Pete Sampras' being a summary level, that counts as a '1' even if there are no tennis reports actually linked to that record.

Is that correct? Or is this displaying '1' for another particular reason? Also, is there an intelligent (lazy) way to get around this and make '1' display '0' when there aren't any tennis reports linked to a tennis player?

I am aware of the approaches to handle this in a more 'water tight' way such as using custom code, workflow rule, 'power of one' formula, using a package like https://github.com/SFDO-Community/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries or changing the relationship between the objects from lookup to a master-detail and then creating a roll-up summary field. But I wonder if there's a way for me to handle this without those aforementioned approaches (it doesn't seem like there is because summary fields cannot reference other summary fields so there doesn't seem a 'hacky' way around it).